# error when executing query in linqpad

Tags: linqpad

I have just started using LinqPad:

```
var con1 = from con in table
where con.tableKey == Guid.Parse("8EA5DC2C-2603-499A-A9D3-00019B53421F")
select con;

con.Dump();
```

throws me error

```
") or end of expression expected (change the Query Language to 'C# Statements' for multi-statement queries)"
```

Can anyone please correct me?

And also i have notices File-> New Query, New Query same properties on linqpad.
What is the difference between them? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your type of query is C# statements and not C# expression... but if you aren't doing more than 1 statement you don't need the con.Dump(); (I think)

Comment: Can you please also let me know the difference between File-> New Query, New Query same properties

Comment: "New Query Same Properties" creates a new query while copying over the current query's properties, including query language, connection, references and additional namespaces.